# why does inferior exit "normally" when i use dprintf in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I'm running a very trivial program (just a main with some random int assignments) to test out `dprintf` from gdb. A main which looks like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int h = 17;
    int k = 42;
    std::cout << "stop here" << std::endl;
}
```

(the `h` part is line 5). I set the `dprintf 6,"h is %d\n",h` and if i say `start` I am taken to line `5` as expected..if I then say `advance 7` the program exits even though `7` is the `std::cout` - why is this? (if I don't use dprintf and I say `advance 7` I do, indeed, break on the `std::cout` line..)

Comment: What is `dprintf`?  That's not a standard gdb command.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield It is a new "standard" GDB command: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dynamic-Printf.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is this?

It's a bug in GDB. You can report it in GDB [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb).